# Visual Studio 2010, NVIDIA AndroidWorks and some questions about debugging Android Apps

Tags: android, visual-studio-2010, android-ndk, nvidia, nsight

I have a Visual Studio 2010 Professional.I've installed NVIDIA AndroidWorks.I have a tablet with Android 4.1.1 also.I`ve been tried to debug simple android NDK application in Visual Studio 2010 Professional on my device, but I received some error 'Failed to attach: Android 4.1(API level 16) devices are not currently supported'.
Сan I somehow solve this problem or debugger really currently does not support Android 4.1 device?If not supported, are there plans for this in future versions NVIDIA AndroidWorks?I do not have the ability to upgrade the operating system on my tablet.

Comment: _"are there plans for this in future versions NVIDIA AndroidWorks?"_ That sounds like something you should ask NVidia, not the StackOverflow community.

Comment: I meant that maybe someone from the community heard or read something about it.I just found nothing of the sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In General, wrote on the NVIDIA forum and got the answer, maybe someone will be useful:"There is a bug pertaining to API level 16 devices that makes debugging native code on them impossible. We've decided to fail earlier with an error message instead of letting people get to the buggy behavior.

So, unfortunately, you can't debug on a Android 4.1 device. As a workaround, you could try downgrading the device to API level 15 or installing a custom firmware (such as CyanogenMod) that is based on a later API level than 16."